# How to show a complex nested array of integers in Swagger UI?

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi, nested-lists

One of my POST endpoints has a complex nested arrays of integers. How to show this structure in Swagger UI?

```json
{
    "raw_data": [
                  [
                    [1,2], [4,5], [7,8]
                  ],

                  [
                    [
                     [1,2], [4,5], [7,8]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
}
```

I'm using:

openapi: "3.0.0"
Swagger-jsdoc: "^6.2.5",
Swagger-ui-express: "^4.3.0",
Node: v18.8.0

Comment: Is the array structure always exactly like this? E.g. the first occurrence of `[1,2], [4,5], ...` is 2 levels deep, the second occurrence is 3 levels deep. Or can the nesting levels vary?

Comment: Thanks for your accurate question.. i ask my boss, yes these is the structure and the levels don't vary :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need this exact array every time, you can do this:

```
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "properties": {
                  "raw_data": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "integer"  
                    },
                    "example": [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]], [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]]]]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

The example you used above shows up, but like @Helen mentioned, you do need to make sure the `type` is an array, not an integer.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it. And its show up exactly the same.  I add a descriptions saying that is a nested array of integers. don't you exaplain that inside the items of the array the items are integers ? You give away the example and done?

Comment: Yes, you would specify that the items in the array are integers. I edited my original answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x / 3.1

This example uses `oneOf` to handle different nesting levels of the 1st and 2nd sets of integers.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.3

raw_data:
  type: array
  example: [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]], [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]]]]
  minItems: 2
  maxItems: 2
  items:
    type: array
    items:
      type: array
      items:
        oneOf:
          - type: integer
          - type: array
            items:
              type: integer
```

#### OpenAPI 3.1 only

Since the 1st and 2nd sets of integers have different nesting levels, you can use the [`prefixItems`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#tuple-validation) keyword to define the exact nesting level of each set. You can also add `minItems` and `maxItems` to the inner arrays to define their exact length.

This definition is a bit more verbose that the `oneOf` version above, but it describes the structure more precisely.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

raw_data:
  type: array
  # You can add the example for the root array itself, or split it into separate examples of inner arrays
  example: [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]], [[[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]]]]
  minItems: 2
  maxItems: 2
  prefixItems:
    # The 1st set of integers
    - type: array
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
        example: [[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]]  # optional example
    # The 2nd set of integers
    - type: array
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            type: array
            items:
              type: integer
          example: [[1,2], [4,5], [7,8]]  # optional example
```

Comment: The schemas with your first example shows : 

 [
example: List [ List [ List [ 1, 2 ], List [ 4, 5 ], List [ 7, 8 ] ], List [ List [ List [ 1, 2 ], List [ 4, 5 ], List [ 7, 8 ] ] ] ]


minItems: 2
maxItems: 2


prefixItems: List [ OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "integer" } } } }, OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "array", "items": OrderedMap { "type": "integer" } } } } } ]

Comment: For the second example in my rooter i have openapi 3.0.0 when i change to 3.1.0 doesn't render anything. it sais: "Unable to render this definition"

Comment: Thanks anyway i will keep the first example is more complete than using just writing type: array + example